# Azure AD and Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, azure, active-directory

I’m currently testing the Microsoft Azure and SharePoint 2013 ability.
In our office, we have an Office 365 account, and I have created a Azure 30-days trial subscription. I have connected those two, so our Office 365 users are visible in Azure AD.

We need to install a virtual server with SharePoint installed on it, with access to a SQL server in Azure as well.

Is it possible to use the Azure AD as authentication for SharePoint users?
If possible, we would like to avoid installing an On-premises AD in Azure. We simply need the authentication for our SharePoint users, so we can keep everything in the cloud, without Site to site VPN to our in house AD.

I am aware, that the virtual machine in Azure with Sharepoint on it, will run in a Workgroup, but I have a hard time figuring out, how I can access the Azure AD to lookup users. I don’t know if this is possible.

Best regards
Christian